# Have any online-exclusive series won an Emmy?

Tags: awards

We're experiencing a steady increase of shows and mini-series being exclusively available on the Internet. Have any won an Emmy (in any category)?

Comment: This [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Primetime_Emmy_Award_winners) shows the winners and the networks attached to each show.

Comment: As @wbogacz has shown, a little research on your part would have given you the answer. Please remember that we really appreciate questions that show some work... often because it makes the question unnecessary. :D

Comment: Not that I'm disagreeing that with a little research they would have answered their own question, but the chart that @wbogacz linked to only shows the winners for seven of the twenty-seven categories that awards are given in.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. Additionally, the full roster per year is one click removed from this same page. It contains all the additional awards. I hate having become an instrument in a "search the easy stuff" resolution.

Comment: I'm sorry for the rollback but if you have a **new question** please ask it rather than changing this question. This question already has an answer and it is not accepted policy to significantly alter questions after they've been answered. That being said, your new question is interesting and I encourage you to ask it... but in the proper manner.

Comment: @catija Did you happen to save it before you changed it back, or is there a way I could access that myself? I don't recall my particular wording.

Comment: @Valerie Just look at the edit history. It's all there. (click on the "edited _ minutes ago" button).

Comment: @catija Thank you! And thank you for your patience... I am (obviously) insanely new to this. But I'm learning!

Comment: Welcome :D And thank you for being a willing learner. Many people get an attitude when we try to explain how the site works. It's nice to find someone willing to listen. :D

Comment: @Catija - I think the "new" question would quickly be closed as off topic, as it invites speculation about future possibilities.

Comment: @JohnP It also specifically asks for references. I agree that it's subjective but it's the sort of subjective question that I believe can easily be supported with factual information.

Answer (score 6):

Netflix exclusive House of Cards won an Emmy for "Outstanding Director of a Drama Series" at the 65th Emmy Awards in 2013 http://www.emmys.com/awards/nominees-winners/2013?page=4

Comment: And, by a visual scan of the past 5 years, this seems to be the only one.